# girdlayout rezize depending on how many rows

Tags: java, netbeans

I got a Jpanel that is inside a Jpanel that is inside a JSplitpane (so buttons appear the same.) and the split pane to expand showing all buttons not the top ones in the grid layout.

the grid layout is made so it uses 5 columns but an undecided number of rows. (rows = 0). I'm adding all buttons that are visible to the grid. (all buttons start as invisible and then flipped if they meet requirements for an upgrade)

but when i add buttons to the grid i first need to remove the buttons already existing in the Jpanel `Jpanel.removeAll();` and then add the buttons whit an if checking if they are visable inside a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<buttons.size(); i++){
    class button = buttons.get(i);
    JButton switch = button.getJButton();
    if(switch.isVisible()){
        jpanel.add(switch);
    }
}
```

this adds all buttons in the wanted order however the panel is the same size making the grid drag out the buttons that were placed whit in it to fit the whole panel.
I tried setting the size of the panel by doing calculations depending on the number of components within the panel divided by 5 to get the rows and then take that number times the size I want the buttons. this, however, does absolutely nothing.

I'm thinking it might have something whit me having resizable set to true on one of those 3 making it impossible for resizing it. but i don't know what to test anymore.

(I'm trying to create the upgrades panel that cookie clicker uses in java and I have gotten the jsplitpanel to extend the upgrades panel like in the game on hower but the buttons are all dragged out)

if I fail whit this plan I will just do a manual layout, and add 5 at each row and then go to the next whit some kind of for loop or something

Comment: I tried using `.setSize`, `.setPreferredSize`, `.setMaximumSize` and `.setMinimumSize` when chaning size of the panel i also tried to do `.revalidate`afterwards.

Comment: Call [pack()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) on the Frame containing your panel.

Comment: Do I only need to call pack or do I need to resize panel and then do pack()?
and how do I do it on my JFrame? NetBeans does not name the frame.

Comment: The panel will compute its own preferred size, based on its children.  `pack()` makes the window resize itself to accommodate its child components’ preferred sizes.  So, you should not need to resize the panel.